# SSH tunnel in .ssh/config with public key on second leg

Tags: ssh, openssh, public-key

I want to reach Ubuntu20.04 server `U1` through Ubuntu20.04 server `U2` since `U1` is behind a firewall, from a MacBook with BugSur. SSH from U2 to U1 is done with a public key, without password. I get to `U2` using password but the next step always asks for a password (which I can't remember now). I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57780250/does-vscode-remote-support-double-ssh) and tried things like this in the MacBook's `.ssh/config`:

```
Host U2
    HostName accessible.uni.com
    User me
    # PreferredAuthentications publickey
    ForwardX11 yes

Host U1
    HostName behind_firewall.uni.com
    User me
    # PreferredAuthentications publickey
    # IdentityFile /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
    ProxyJump U2
    ForwardX11 yes
```

and running `ssh U1` enter the password for `U2` but is then asked for password for `U1`. How can I make it work password-free on the second ssh?

Comment: You can use RemoteCommand [Example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354594/remote-command-in-ssh-config-file)

Comment: Can you run an authentication agent on your laptop, loading your key in the agent and forwarding the connection using the `-A` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Remote Command. Once it's successfully connected to U2 it will execute the command ssh U1.

```sh
Host U1
    HostName accessible.uni.com
    User me
    # PreferredAuthentications publickey
    ForwardX11 yes
    RemoteCommand ssh U1
```

Comment: Thanks! It works with `ssh -t U1` or if adding `RequestTTY force` to your definition. And `U1` must be defined in the `.ssh/config` of `U2`.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently each leg of the tunnel with `ProxyJump` want's to be authenticated by a key (or password) from the MacBook in this case. So making a public key and adding it to `authorized_keys` of each computer where it should pass by password-less is necessary with this option.