# Enter commands in VSCode's Remote-SSH environment

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I am using the `VSCode` extension `Remote-SSH` to connect to a remote server.

However, on this server, I can only login via the login node. I'm not allowed to run heavy tasks on this node, so I need to enter `voltash` to get transferred to a usable node.

I can do this by opening a new terminal. However, the current node remains unchanged on Remote-SSH:

[image]

Even though the terminal window says I am on `n-62-27-20` (the name of the node I'm currently on, in the terminal), the Remote-SSH status bar (bottom left) still is on the `login` node.

**My question is: is there a way to enter this `voltash` command inside the Remote-SSH extension?**

I found this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57780250/does-vscode-remote-support-double-ssh](https://link) however, I can't enter a server IP as I need to use a command (`voltash`).