# VSCode remote-ssh connection with ProxyJump from command line without config file

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, vscode-remote

I am trying to use VSCode's extension remote-ssh from CLI to connect to a server through a ProxyJump.

For now, I am using an ssh config file that has the following structure:

```
Host myserver
        ProxyJump user@jumpserver
        User user
        ForwardX11 true
        ForwardX11Trusted yes
        Hostname remoteserver
```

and from CLI I can open a folder on the server with:

```
code --folder-uri "vscode-remote://ssh-remote+myserver/path/to/folder"
```

Do you know if is possible to open such a folder without the need for a config file?

Edit:
To be more clear, I already know the possibility for VScode to connect to a folder in an ssh server without config file, but simply using command line, via:

```
code --folder-uri "vscode-remote://ssh-remote+username@server_ip_address/path/to/folder"
```

I want to know if there is the same possibility, but using a jump server.

Answer (score 0):

check out this this question [Does vscode remote support double ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57780250/does-vscode-remote-support-double-ssh)

```
Host myserver
        ProxyJump myproxyserver
        User user
        ForwardX11 true
        ForwardX11Trusted yes
        Hostname remoteserver.com

Host myproxyserver
        ProxyJump user@jumpserver
        User proxyUser
        ForwardX11 true
        ForwardX11Trusted yes
        Hostname proxyhostname.com
```

Comment: This is basically what I do. 
As I specified in the question, I already set the proxy server in the ssh config file and everything works.
However, I would just to do the same without having an SSH config file at all, but by specifying everything in the command line. 
I edited the question to make it more clear.